# On enabling Spring plugins in IntelliJ, some plugin are showing error that 'com.spring.intellij not installed'

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

On enabling Spring plugins in IntelliJ, some plugin are showing error that 'com.spring.intellij not installed'. Not able to install the Spring IntelliJ plugin.

Comment: which edition Idea are you using? Community edition or Enterprise?

Comment: community, version 14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition does not include the support for Spring. Spring is only available in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.